# Safari searches instead of connecting to localhost

Tags: safari

I am launching a jupiter-notebook on port 8888, but when I try to connect with Safari the browser goes automatically to search.

Firefox and Chrome work just fine, as Safari did before the last update. 
Anyone else with the same problem? I checked a couple of posts recommended by StackOverflow (mostly about commenting the "::1 localhost" line in /etc/hosts) but it did not work.

Anyone else with the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
It was related to the "Startpage" extension. Startpage is a search engine that is supposed to be private. However, it searches from the address bar, and I guess it does not recognize localhost.